# mac os, after npm update I get strange errors, when I open a terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

When I start new terminal - I see the error.

I press Enter - and then I can work normally.

Why this happens and how to fix this?

```
apower ~/Desktop/t1 node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:823:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:835:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/cli-logger.js:52:20)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:205:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:143:22)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}

Node.js v18.2.0
apower ~/Desktop/t1
```

```
apower ~/Desktop/t1 npm -v
8.12.1
apower ~/Desktop/t1 node -v
v18.2.0
```

Comment: I have upgraded note.js to v18.3.0 - the error still persists. I believe it's because of a global @angular/cli (v14.0.0)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45870#issuecomment-1118696409

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky yes, I read from ng version info that the node version 18 is not supported yet, by Angular 14. Now I've downgrades node to 16.15.1 - but the error still persists. The npm version is 8.11 now

Comment: ok, they have fixed the error in 14.0.1